# How to pull unrelated data in a column from two tables.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following two tables:

**BenPlan**

```
BenPlanId   BenPlanName   BenPlanRate   EmployeeCost
-----------------------------------------------------
1           Medical       0.45          5000
2           Dental        0.75          2000
```

**EmployeeBenPlan**

```
EmployeeId   BenPlanId   EffectiveStart   EffectiveEnd
-------------------------------------------------------
1            1           1/1/2019         NULL
2            2           1/1/2019         NULL
```

Now, I have to make a report which shows data as under:

EmployeeBenPlanDetails

```
EmployeeId   BenPlanName   Rate    EmployeeCost   EffectiveStart    EffectiveEnd
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            Medical       0.75    5000           1/1/2019          NULL
2            Dental        0.75    2000           1/1/2019          NULL
```

That is, even when the ben plan is medical, I need to show the rate for Dental plan in the Rate column, or should I say, the rate column should display the result of following query:

```
SELECT Rate
FROM BenPlan
WHERE BenPlanName = 'Dental'
```

How can we do this?

Comment: If there is more than one record in `BenPlan` with `BenPlanName  = 'Dental'`, how do we choose which one should be picked?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following query returns your expected result. It always returns `Rate` of the Dental plan.

```
SELECT
    EmployeeBenPlan.EmployeeId
    ,BenPlan.BenPlanName
    ,(
        SELECT Rate
        FROM BenPlan
        WHERE BenPlanName = 'Dental'
    ) AS Rate
    ,BenPlan.EmployeeCost
    ,EmployeeBenPlan.EffectiveStart
    ,EmployeeBenPlan.EffectiveEnd
FROM
    EmployeeBenPlan
    INNER JOIN BenPlan ON BenPlan.BenPlanId = EmployeeBenPlan.BenPlanId
;
```

If the table `BenPlan` can have more than one row where `BenPlanName = 'Dental'`, then you should somehow pick a single row. You can add `TOP(1)` with a suitable `ORDER BY` to the subquery.

```
        SELECT TOP(1) Rate
        FROM BenPlan
        WHERE BenPlanName = 'Dental'
        ORDER BY BenPlanId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution. This solution also works in case you are adding new records on `BenPlan`:

```
SELECT ebp.EmployeeId, bp.BenPlanName, bp.BenPlanRate AS Rate, bp.EmployeeCost, ebp.EffectiveStart, ebp.EffectiveEnd
FROM EmployeeBenPlan ebp INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b1.BenPlanId, b1.BenPlanName, b1.EmployeeCost,
    CASE WHEN b1.BenPlanName = 'Medical' THEN b2.BenPlanRate ELSE b1.BenPlanRate END AS BenPlanRate
  FROM BenPlan b1 LEFT JOIN BenPlan b2 ON b1.BenPlanName = 'Medical' AND b2.BenPlanName = 'Dental'   
) bp ON ebp.BenPlanId = bp.BenPlanId
ORDER BY ebp.EmployeeId, ebp.BenPlanId
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=29ef5388a14a0298bd98d0e12ec6d9c7)

Answer (score 0):

you can write this query

```
SELECT E.EmployeeId,B.BenPlanName,(SELECT TOP(1) Rate
                                    FROM BenPlan
                                    WHERE BenPlanName = 'Dental') AS Rate,
        B.EmployeeCost,E.EffectiveStart,E.EffectiveEnd   
FROM BenPlan B
INNER JOIN EmployeeBenPlan E ON B.BenPlanId   = E.BenPlanId
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want two joins to `benplan`, one just for "Dental" and one for the name of the actual plan:

```
select ebp.EmployeeId, bp.BenPlanName,
       bpd.Rate, bp.EmployeeCost,   
       ebp.EffectiveStart, epb.EffectiveEnd
from employeebenplan ebp join
     benplan bp
     on ebp.BenPlanId = bp.BenPlanId join
     benplan bpd
     on bpd.BenPlanName = 'Dental'
```